"Wa" particle influence on the overall meaning
Swiftly, I want to know whether will there be a semantic change if we add "wa" in this sentence?
Original sentence is:
日本の食べ物何が好きですか。
And this sentence:
日本の食べ物は何が好きですか。

The overall meaning is the same, but "日本の食べ物は何が好きですか" is the formal correct Japanese sentence. The particle は is commonly dropped in informal speech, so "日本の食べ物何が好きですか" is okay in colloquial Japanese. However, this is considered highly broken in written Japanese.
